# C# rabbitMQ consumer with custom injected handler

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have this method the consume messages from a rabbitMq queue

```
public void ConsumeMessage(string queueName, IMessagingHandler messageHandler)
{
    if (messageHandler == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(messageHandler)} can not be null");

    var connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
    var channel = connection.CreateModel();
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    //consumer.Received+= ConsumerOnReceived;
    consumer.Received +=async (model, ea) => 
    {
        _logger.Info($"Message received");

        var message = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (ea.Body == null)
            {
                _logger.Error("Null Message Body");
                //TODO this should throw a red flag notification error
                return;
            }

            var body = ea.Body;
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            var packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessagingPackage>(message);

            _logger.Info($"Message decoded {message}");

            await messageHandler.HandleMessage(packet);

            _logger.Info($"Message passed to handler {messageHandler}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.Message,ex);
            throw;
        }
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(
        queue: queueName,
        autoAck: true,
        consumer: consumer);

}
```

Notice there is a `IMessagingHandler messageHandler`, that is passed into the method as a parameter.

The problem i am running into that that when the `consumer.Received +=async (model, ea)` event is executed the variable `messageHandler` is null.

I am taking this approach because I want the consumer to generic while being able to implement any custom handler for the messages that come out that queue, as it is part of 3rd party integrations.

So my question is there a way to make sure that `messageHandler` variable wont be null when the event is fired?

Comment: Just save it inside body of async callback and use it instead, i.e:  *var hndl = messageHandler;*

Comment: @eocron i am actually trying something like that now.  I saved the parameter to a call level variable and im using that.  Im about to test it.  If it works then I will let you know Add that answer and Ill mark it correct.